# Create view from multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm currently doing a sql script using the following tables in a database:

Menu table (contains the information about dishes):

```
+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+
| id_plato | nombre_plato | precio | tipo        | 
+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+
|        1 | peces        |    100 | entrada     |
|        2 | caca         |     20 | rolls_fondo |
|        3 | plato1       |    200 | bajativo    |
|        4 | plato2       |    200 | entrada     |
|        5 | plato3       |    200 | entrada     |
|        6 | plato4       |    200 | entrada     |
|        7 | plato5       |    200 | entrada     |
|        8 | plato6       |    200 | entrada     |
|        9 | plato7       |    200 | entrada     |
|       10 | plato8       |    200 | entrada     |
|       11 | plato9       |    200 | entrada     |
|       12 | plato10      |    200 | entrada     |
|       13 | plato11      |    200 | entrada     |
|       14 | plato1       |    200 | entrada     |
+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+
```

Boleta table (contains the informatio of all sales):

```
+-----------+------+--------------+
| id_boleta | sexo | precio_final |
+-----------+------+--------------+
|         1 | m    |            1 |
|         2 | f    |            1 |
|         3 | f    |            1 |
|         4 | m    |            1 |
+-----------+------+--------------+
```

BoletaDetalle table (contains the information of each dish bought on a given sale):

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
| id_detalle | id_boleta | id_plato | precio_detalle |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|          1 |         1 |        1 |              1 |
|          2 |         1 |        1 |              1 |
|          3 |         1 |        2 |           1990 |
|          4 |         2 |        1 |              5 |
|          5 |         3 |        4 |              1 |
|          6 |         4 |        2 |              1 |
|          7 |         5 |        4 |              1 |
|          8 |         4 |        2 |              1 |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

Basically, this is a small program for a small restaurant and I have been asked to show a quick report trough an sql script that displays a view containing the favorite dish of a certain group of costumers. For example, based on costumer's gender as follows:

```
| Sex |    Type    |
+------------------+
|  M  |  entrada   |
|  F  |  bajativo  |
```

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out despite of it being an easy task.

This is what I have so far:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1;
CREATE VIEW v1 (Tipo, CantidadMujer, CantidadHombre)
    AS
    SELECT m.tipo as Tipo, COUNT(bd.id_plato) as 'Cantidad Mujer', COUNT(bd2.id_plato) as 'Cantidad Hombre'
    FROM Menu m
    LEFT JOIN BoletaDetalle bd
    INNER JOIN Boleta b
        on (bd.id_boleta = b.id_boleta AND b.sexo = 'f')
    on bd.id_plato = m.id_plato AND m.tipo = 'entrada'
    LEFT JOIN BoletaDetalle bd2
    INNER JOIN Boleta b2
        on (bd2.id_boleta = b2.id_boleta AND b2.sexo = 'm')
    on bd2.id_plato = m.id_plato AND m.tipo = 'entrada'
    GROUP BY(m.tipo);
SELECT * FROM v1;
```

I was thinking of creating a view like the one above with the amount of dishes bought per each gender (on each dish type) and then create a second view (the final one) by getting the maximum value per category. I'm really lost here so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE VIEW sexo_tipo_view AS
SELECT b.sexo, m.tipo, COUNT(d.id_plato) total
  FROM boletadetalle d JOIN boleta b
    ON d.id_boleta = b.id_boleta JOIN menu m
    ON d.id_plato = m.id_plato
 GROUP BY b.sexo, m.tipo
 ORDER BY sexo, total DESC;

CREATE VIEW sexo_tipo_favorites_view AS
SELECT sexo, tipo
  FROM sexo_tipo_view
 GROUP BY sexo;

SELECT s.sexo, COALESCE(v.tipo, '-') tipo
  FROM 
(
  SELECT 'f' sexo UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'm'
) s LEFT JOIN sexo_tipo_favorites_view v
    ON s.sexo = v.sexo;
```

or without views

```
SELECT s.sexo, COALESCE(v.tipo, '-') tipo
  FROM
(
  SELECT 'f' sexo UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'm'
) s LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT sexo, tipo
    FROM
  (
    SELECT b.sexo, m.tipo, COUNT(d.id_plato) total
      FROM boletadetalle d JOIN boleta b
        ON d.id_boleta = b.id_boleta JOIN menu m
        ON d.id_plato = m.id_plato
     GROUP BY b.sexo, m.tipo
     ORDER BY sexo, total DESC
  ) a
   GROUP BY sexo
) v
   ON s.sexo = v.sexo;
```

Sample output (in both cases):

```
| SEXO |        TIPO |
|------|-------------|
|    f |     entrada |
|    m | rolls_fondo |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2813c/3)** demo

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I was looking for. I'll take a deep look at the code as at a first look it seems really confusing to me and I may ask a few questions if you don't mind. Again, thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome :) Don't hesitate to ask a follow up question.

Comment: I ran into an issue. If I clear the database and insert female only sales, it won't display the statistics for male customers (obviously as there are no sales containing male customers). Is there a workaround to detect this and possibly put a '-' on TIPO?

Comment: You need to use `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` function for this. See updated answer. And here is a new [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d534f/3) example that shows this in action.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks again for taking the time to reply, you've helped me a lot.